# Check if variable is not [prevObject]: fn.init[0]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
if(direction == 'prev') {
    var desired_img = main_image_thumb.parent().parent().prev().find('img');
}
else {
    var desired_img = main_image_thumb.parent().parent().next().find('img');
}
console.log(desired_img);
```

If variable desired_img is ok, console.log will give me `[img#532.thumb ....].` 
If it is not ok, I will get `[prevObject: e.fn.init[0],...]`, this is when there is no image after.

This is the print screen of these two console.logs
[image]

How can I check if variable is not `[prevObject: e.fn.init[0], contexxt...]`?
Because then I would like to switch direction

Comment: Looks like X-Y problem

Comment: can you provide HTML part of your code?